# Tagging people in Lightroom 3 before publishing to Facebook

Tags: lightroom, lightroom-3, facebook

I am snapping a lot of pictures and lots of them I upload to Facebook. Is there any plugin out there to tag people in my catalogs?

Answer (score 3):

At this moment I don't know any plugin that will do that.
You can combine Picasa and Lightroom... more information on google http://lmgtfy.com/?q=lightroom+facebook+tag+people

Answer (score 1):

Jeffrey Friedl produces a number of excellent Lightroom plugins and I notice he's got a new one for importing face data from Picasa:

http://regex.info/blog/lightroom-goodies/picasa-face-import

I haven't tried it though, so I can't say if it does what you're after, but it might be worth a look?